# Can we select server location of salesforce?

Tags: sales, basics

Is it possible for us to select specific location of Salesforce Sales cloud while purchase ?
i.e. : Server should be at Ohio.

Comment: it has to be Ohio and not anywhere in the US?

Comment: Ohio is just for the example. I just want to know, is it possible to select one of the available server while purchasing ?  :)

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce [publicly documents](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314281&type=1&mode=1) the location of the data centers serving its instances. US data centers are located in Chicago, Dallas, Phoenix, and Washington, DC. There are no instances documented to be served from the state of Ohio.

Note from the linked document:

> At any given time, a Salesforce instance is actively served from one location with transactions replicating in near real-time to a completely redundant, secondary location. We regularly site switch between the locations for maintenance, compliance, and disaster recovery purposes. As we continue to expand and improve our global infrastructure presence, we recommend customers build their applications free of specific data center requirements to support a seamless Salesforce experience.